# Are there any domain specific global variables in PHP?

Tags: php, wamp

I have 2 websites running on my localhost

1. localhost/sample_website1/index.php
2. localhost/sample_website2/index.php

**initial code in both the websites is:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:home.php")
}
// This code redirects index.php to home.php if the session already exists

.........next lines are login code..........
// 
// 
// 
            
............................................
```

I have successfully logged into sample_website1 using the login form in index.php and the session is activated. `$_SESSION['user']=$username`

Now I opened a new tab and visited sample_website2 in which it is using the session variable $_SESSION['user'] that is already set in sample_website1 and automatically logging into home.php from index.php

I need a session variable that will be active only in sample_website1 so that it will not directly authenticate user on some other website like sample_website2.

Comment: use ```session_name("sample_websiteN");``` before ```session_start()``` (replace N with 1 or 2), see http://php.net/session_name

Comment: or use [session_set_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) path option to the current directory

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION['sample_website1']['user']` and `$_SESSION['sample_website2']['user']` but you'll have to access them accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I believe OP is merely running 2 folders on one domain...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - That would make sense! :-)

Answer (score 1):

use `session_name("sample_websiteN");` before `session_start()` (replace N with 1 or 2), see php.net/session_name

in localhost/sample_website1/index.php

```php
<?php
session_name("sample_website1");
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:home.php")
}
// This code redirects index.php to home.php if the session already exists

.........next lines are login code..........
// 
// 
// 
            
............................................
```

in localhost/sample_website2/index.php

```php
<?php
session_name("sample_website2");
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:home.php")
}
// This code redirects index.php to home.php if the session already exists

.........next lines are login code..........
// 
// 
// 
            
............................................
```

Explanation from php.net: `The session name references the name of the session, which is used in cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID)`

With this solution, you can deploy your code in same domain and in different domain with perfectly same behavior. You can host both directory in localhost/sample_website1/index.php and localhost/sample_website2/index.php OR in sample_website1.com/index.php and sample_website2.com/index.php with same code

If the session name seems ugly to be hardcoded, then save the session name string somewhere in a configuration file

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if it seems ugly to be hardcoded then save the session name somewhere in a configuration file

Comment: I upvoted but one improvement suggestion would be to automatically read the first directory of the current page path instead of using a hardcoded string. Makes things easier for when `sample_website3` is released! Presumably OP is just copying code from one site to another anyways so the less hardcoding the better.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus then if the OP decided to deploy the code to sample_website1.com/index.php and sample_website2.com/index.php it wouldn't work since there's no first directory anymore? And isn't it bad for 2 separate php app to be able to read/write each other's session?

Comment: @Kristian If that happens then there is no further need for `session_name()` so I think that's just a bridge OP needs to cross when they get there. In the grand scheme of things though, yes OP should use a separate domain from the very beginning but I imagine that's a bit too advanced given the question at hand.